# How to extend regex to accept @ in image urls

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group

I have a regex for validating image urls, however some of the images are using `@` for example:
https://test.com/image-name@2x.jpeg.

How can I extend this regex to accept also the `@` character inside of the image link?

Current regex look like this

```js
(http(s?):)([/|.|\w|\s|-])*\.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png)
```

Comment: You can add it to the character class, and perhaps shorten the pattern a bit to `https?:\/\/[\/.\w\s@-]*\.(?:jpe?g|gif|png)` https://regex101.com/r/t0a3ct/1 Or if it could only be part of the image name `https?:\/\/[/.\w\s-]*\/[\w@-]+\.(?:jpe?g|gif|png)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it can only be part of the image name, you can add a forward slash followed by matching the allowed chars including the @ before the last dot before the extension.

You can use a character class for the single chars instead of a grouping structure to match one of the listed characters.

If you don't need the capturing groups, you can omit them to get a match only.

```
https?:\/\/[/.\w\s-]+\/[\w@-]+\.(?:jpe?g|gif|png)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hJmHN9/1)